# Cassini and IISExpress PUT/DELETE Verbs cause 405 Http Code

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

I am currently having an issue running a [Jessica](http://jessicafx.org/) application via VS2010 and Cassini.  The code below is what I am running however when I attempt to use either PUT or DELETE verbs I get a 405 Method Not Allowed response.  I tried the answer suggested at [ASP.NET MVC got 405 error on HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760607/asp-net-mvc-got-405-error-on-http-delete-request) but this did not work for me.  I have also copied in my minimal web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*Code*

```
public class UserModule : JessModule
{
    public UserModule() : base("/user")
    {
        Get("/", r => View("list", UserRepository.GetAllUsers()));

        Post("/", r =>
        {
            AddUser(new User { EmailAddress = r.EmailAddress, Name = r.Name });
            return Response.AsRedirect("/user");
        });

        Get("/edit/:id", r => View("edit", UserRepository.GetUser(int.Parse(r.id))));

        Put("/:id", r =>
        {
            EditUser(r.id, new User { EmailAddress = r.EmailAddress, Name = r.Name });
            return Response.AsRedirect("/user");
        });

        Delete("/:id", r =>
        {
            DeleteUser(r.id);
            return Response.AsRedirect("/user");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find this bit of information intresting as well http://ravendb.net/faq/405-method-not-allowed

Comment: Yeah that was the suggested answer to the question I linked above.  It did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's always been like that, the ASP.NET development server has its limits. I would recommend getting VS2010 SP1 and the IIS Express components through the Platform Web Installer. It will give you the same development experience without the quirks of Cassini.

Comment: Nope same problem with IIS Express.  Method not allowed.

Comment: 'tis it not just that the default mappings only allow GET and POST?

Comment: I can't get WebDAV to work at all on standard 2008 server. Tried every single post on SO and server fault.

Answer (score 0):

Put verb should work with IIS Express and for this you need to enable WebDAV (IIS Express installs WebDAV but it does not enable it by default). And also WebDAV does not work with anonymous authentication. So you need to enable WebDAV, disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication. Follow below steps;

1.Find following three entries in the applicationhost.config file located in user profile(%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config) and un-comment them (by default they are commented)

```
<add name="WebDAVModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\webdav.dll" />
<add name="WebDAVModule" />
<add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

Note: Above three elements are not at one place in the configuration file.

2.Add following configuration entry at the end of the applicationhost.config file (Just before `'</configuration>'` element )

```
<location path="WebSite1"> 
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="false">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
        <webdav>
            <authoring enabled="true" />
            <authoringRules>
                <add users="*" path="*" access="Read, Write, Source" />
            </authoringRules>
        </webdav>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Note: In the above config entry replace 'WebSite1' with your site name

3.Restart IIS Express

4.Now try PUT/DELETE request

Comment: A quick google of the topic reveals that WebDAV should not be used, and is in fact causing trouble and i would advice against it. It is likely that this is a simple configuration issue that has to be done to allow more http verbs by default.

Comment: why WebDAV should not be used? could you share the link which advices not to use it. I beleive there is no default handler in IIS for PUT verb!

Comment: See this thread http://forums.iis.net/t/1166025.aspx and this one http://forums.iis.net/t/1163441.aspx they explicitly go into details on how WebDAV is the culprit

Comment: It's true that WebDAV claim PUT/DELETE etc... verbs. If you have any other module which claim these verbs, then it would be an issue. Othewise you can use WebDAV.