# ASP.NET Web API Custom PUT Method not working (returns 404)

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a custom PUT method in my API, following the instructions at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api.

My API:

```
public class AlarmStatusController : ApiController
{
    // Other methods here (removed for brevity)

    [HttpPut]
    public void ResetAlarmTimeout(long AlarmID)
    {
        // Do stuff (removed for brevity)
    }
}
```

My call to the method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/AlarmStatus/ResetAlarmTimeout",
    data: { AlarmID: alarmID },
    success: AlarmResetSuccess,
    error: AjaxError
});
```

My API route in public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The ajax call returns 404. If I change the API method and ajax call to a GET, then it works, but this isn't RESTful since my GET method is modifying the object.

Comment: What are you using as a webserver IIS, IIS Express, VS Development server?

Comment: It's probably because your server isn't configured to correctly handle PUT requests, if you're using IIS, you'll need to say which version for help on how to configure.

Comment: I am using the dev server (debug from Visual Studio).

Comment: Doesnt this solve your issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers

Answer (score 2):

Are you using VS2010?  If so you're probably using Cassini, which AFAIK doesn't support `PUT` (see related [Cassini and IISExpress PUT/DELETE Verbs cause 405 Http Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058027/cassini-and-iisexpress-put-delete-verbs-cause-405-http-code)).    IISExpress works well with VS2010,  supports the `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs, etc. and has other advantages, so I'd consider installing that and using it.