# MVC 4. IIS 7.5 PUT returning 405

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, http-status-code-405, http-put, iis-8

I'm trying to use PUT in an MVC 4 application and I'm getting a 405 error.

In my routing I have a constraint on the route to allow PUT and POST, POST to the endpoint works, PUT fails with a 405.

I've followed the advice here [ASP.NET Web API returns 404 for PUT only on some servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers) and here [ASP.NET MVC got 405 error on HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760607/asp-net-mvc-got-405-error-on-http-delete-request)

I've also deleted WeDAV from IIS, but I'm still getting the 405. Anybody have any other suggestions?

I'm also having exactly the same issue on IIS 8 (with Visual Studio 2012), for that I've followed this advice [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-vs2012rc-iis-8) and still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above I'm using the WebAPI and it appears that the WebAPI is 'fussy' over which verbs map to which methods. I ended up having to add the [HttpXXX] attributes (HttpPut, Get, Delete and Post) to the appropriate methods to get the routing to work as I expected it to.

Answer (score 26):

My hosting provider could NOT uninstall WebDAV as this would affect everyone.

This, runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" , worked but was not recommended.

Many fixes included removing the module for WebDAVModule but that still didn't work. I removed the handler also, and finally I could use all verbs POST GET PUT DELETE.

Remove WebDAVModule and WebDAV in modules and handlers.

```
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: My web.config already had the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true".  Adding in the remove WebDAV lines above worked great for me.

Comment: I thought I'd already done this, but I only removed the handler - not the module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Putting my 2 cents in...  Clicking on my site under iis showed 'WebDAV Authoring Rules' as the last entry under 'IIS'.    Double-clicking on that showed 'The WebDAV feature has been disabled.' alert on the right and there was a link for 'Enable WebDAV' but it still didn't work.  I followed Stanomatic's suggestion above, the handlers section didn't matter, and my modules looked like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

I just added the remove in it and that fixed my problem:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```