# Method not Allowed Error in Jquery Ajax Method used

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery Ajax method with Asp.net MVC 3.0

My jQuery Code is

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/HomePage/GetAllCategories",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
    }
});
```

And my Action Method is

```
public JsonResult GetAllCategories()
{
     return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am getting the Error

> POST http://localhost:50500/HomePage/GetAllCategories 405 (Method Not
>   Allowed)

My debugger is not hitting this method.

Comment: Try adding this, [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)] above the getAllCategories method. Woring on something similar, am not really sure if this will fix it though.

Comment: What is the Controller name?

Comment: I dont think this is a coding problem. It is a problem at configuration. Because I used your same code and was not able to repro it. But check this solution - http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2013/04/29/405-method-not-allowed-using-asp-net-web-api/ and also this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760607/asp-net-mvc-got-405-error-on-http-delete-request

Answer (score 1):

You have created GET method in the controller and you have set method type as POST in your jquery AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/HomePage/GetAllCategories",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used both Get and Post but the problem is still same

Answer (score 1):

Just add "/" on the end of the URL:

```
 url: "/HomePage/GetAllCategories/",
```

Answer (score 0):

Set type **GET** in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategories","HomePage")' ,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
    }
});
```

and action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllCategories()
{
     return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If want to do via **POST** then:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategories","HomePage")' ,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (result) {
              alert(result);
        }
    });
```

and action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAllCategories()
    {
         return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Probably be  AllowPost in the second Action.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Method Typs is '[HttpPost]' and return type of the method is  'JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet'. As per my knowledge  this is not possible in MVC.

Comment: we can return JSON reponse after HttpPost

Comment: @EhsanSajjad method was not hitted

Comment: pass url this way: url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategories","HomePage")'
i suspect url is passing wrong

Comment: I hav placed debugger at the BeginRequest, and there url was in correct format

Comment: give a try using Action Helpers as it generates right url from the controller action name and its recommended to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this. I am using a getJson call to try and fetch the same data.

```
$.getJSON("/HomePage/GetAllCategories",        
            function(returnData) {
              alert(returnData);           
           });
```